# Transferrring Remmina credentials to another machine

Tags: installation, debian-bookworm

Looks like time has come to change to an i9 processor and an NVMe drive and to drop my old Debian 11 to a brand new 12 installation. As far as I understand the preferred way for migration from Debian 11 to 12 is rather a new installation.

Is there a safe way to transfer my existing Remmina credentials to a new machine?

I tried using Seahorse lately but I did not succeed. Maybe due to a feature to make Remmina safer?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/420987/680869) answer you can check and backup these directories:

```
~/.remmina 
~/.local/share/remmina
```

Generally speaking your entire home directory (plus hidden directories) must be backed up

Comment: Negative. As far as I see usernames, settings etc. may be copied this way but passwords are not. Passwords are coded on your local system for obvious reasons and copying .remmina folder will not decode them. So by this way you need to type in your saved passwords one-by-one again on your new system. That is not the solution I need because I have too many connections here.

Comment: @TopBanana, did you check? Password and decoding should be done using only info in your local directory (and maybe using some info from the global config)

Comment: You mean copying the whole /home directory, everything? No, I did not try that, will give a try, thank you.